# Retrieving data in parentheses in PHP

Tags: php, explode

I have an array of coordinates. I want to separate them but I couldn't separate them / I couldn't tear them apart.

```
$coordinat = "(40.95213474740299, -74.12069452584228),(40.92801571820852, -74.13065088570556),(40.923735615725754, -74.1521085578247),(40.92801571820852, -74.1660131293579),(40.93566733176708, -74.17562616646728),(40.94980103272796, -74.16120661080322),(40.958616855359615, -74.14472711861572)";
```

I want to print the latitude and longitude in parentheses separately into a variable.

Simply:

```
$latitude= "40.95213474740299, 40.92801571820852, 40.923735615725754.......;
$longitude= "-74.12069452584228, -74.13065088570556, -74.1521085578247......;
```

I tried to separate it with Explode and other methods, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: Hint : there is some difference between `, ` (comma-space separating the long and lat in a coordinate) and `,` (comma - separating coordinates).

Comment: Use `preg_match_all()` to match each pair enclosed in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match_all()` to match the pattern of `(<number>, <number>)`. The capture groups can then be used to create the arrays of latitude and longitude.

```
$coordinat = "(40.95213474740299, -74.12069452584228),(40.92801571820852, -74.13065088570556),(40.923735615725754, -74.1521085578247),(40.92801571820852, -74.1660131293579),(40.93566733176708, -74.17562616646728),(40.94980103272796, -74.16120661080322),(40.958616855359615, -74.14472711861572)";
 
preg_match_all('/\((-?[\d.]+),\s*(-?[\d.]+)\)/', $coordinat, $matches);
$latitude = implode(', ', $matches[1]);
$longitude = implode(', ', $matches[2]);
print_r($latitude);
print_r($longitude);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/av8Afj)

Comment: To match the OP's wanted result, `$latitude = implode(', ', $matches[1]);`